# EF ошибка "New transaction is not allowed..."

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

При попытке выполнить следующий метод:

```
public Service UpdateService(Service service)
{
    Service tmp = Data.Context.Service.Single(o => o.ServiceID == service.ServiceID);
    if (tmp != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Data.Context.Entry(tmp).CurrentValues.SetValues(service);
            Data.Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //Вываливается в исключение
        {
            String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) 
               ? ex.InnerException.Message
               : "";

            return null;
        }
    }
    return service;
}
```

На вызове `Data.Context.SaveChanges();` вываливается в исключение следующего содержания:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running
>   in the session.

Для справки - класс Service:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Service
{
    public Service()
    {
        this.BedSchedule = new HashSet<BedSchedule>().ToList();
        this.Order = new HashSet<Order>().ToList();
    }

    [DataMember]
public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public int Duration { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public double Cost { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public bool isActive { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
public virtual IList<BedSchedule> BedSchedule { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public virtual IList<Order> Order { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: метод выполняется асинхронно и один контекст на все потоки?

Comment: @Umed метод синхронный, один контекст, но в этот момент других запросов гарантированно не выполняется.

Comment: Возможно, у Вас есть обращение к контексту в момент вызова функции, которое не завершено (не закрыто)

Comment: Что то такое определенно есть, ошибка же не может взяться из ниоткуда. В английском SO такую ошибку все время связывают с расположением SaveChanges(); внутри цикла foreach. И примеров, где бы была иная причина такого сообщения я так и не нашел ни в рунете ни "за бугром".

Comment: Уже сейчас я понимаю, что использовать DbContext, объявленный как public static в отдельном статическом классе- это порочная практика. Я попробую сделать "как пишут везде" - объявлять отдельный экземпляр DbContext по мере необходимости. С другой стороны попробую использовать метод SaveChangesAsync(); Возможно что то из этого решит проблему. О результатах, разумеется, сообщу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в первую очередь заключалась в том, что `DbContext` был объявлен как `public static` в отдельном статическом классе и проблему решало создание нового экземпляра `DbContext` каждый раз:

```
    using (var context = new MainDBEntities())
     {
       ...
     }
```

Повозившись с разными вариантами каскадного обновления `Entity` с `Navigation Property`, я наткнулся на библиотеку GraphDiff в NuGet`(PM> Install-Package GraphDiff)`.

Я использую ее всего несколько часов и не осмелюсь рекомендовать, но пока что она решила все мои проблемы с каскадным обновлением.

Вот так теперь выглядит метод `ServiceUpdate`:

```
 public Service UpdateService(Service service)
        {
                try
                {
                    using (var context = new MainDBEntities())
                    {
                        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                        context.UpdateGraph(service, map => map.AssociatedEntity(x => x.Department)
                                                                .AssociatedEntity(x => x.Category));
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   //обработчик
                }
             return service;
        }
```

*P.S. Поскольку я решил свою проблему с использованием нестандартной библиотеки, варианты с "ванильными" решениями приветствуются.*

Comment: Ванильное решение см. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795506/213987), отдельным ответом добавлять не буду.