# Не редактируются и не удаляются данные в БД, EF6 C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Добрый день! Подскажите как решить вопрос с записью в БД измененных данных или удалением их. Данные во `view` выводятся, в контроллер передаются, но изменений не происходит, выводит ошибку. Проблема где-то в контроллере когда пытаюсь изменить данные типа `IList`. В таком виде изменяются значения только свойств `Customer`, не `IList`. Как должен выглядеть код, чтобы все изменения учитывались?

Текст ошибки:

> Attaching an entity of type 'CustomerApp.Models.Phone' failed because
>   another entity of the same type already has the same primary key
>   value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the
>   state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the
>   graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities
>   are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In
>   this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track
>   the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' as appropriate.

Модель:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Адрес")]
    public IList<Address> Addresses
    {
        get
        {
            return this._address;
        }

        set => this._address = value;
    }

    private IList<Address> _address = new List<Address>();

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Телефон")]
    public IList<Phone> Phones
    {
        get
        {
            return this._phones;
        }

        set => this._phones = value;
    }

    private IList<Phone> _phones = new List<Phone>();

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("E-mail")]
    public IList<Email> Emails
    {
        get
        {
            return this._email;
        }

        set => this._email = value;
    }

    private IList<Email> _email = new List<Email>();

    [DisplayName("Обновлен")]
    public IList<ProfileUpdate> ProfileUpdates { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Заметка")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Аккаунт")]
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true; // по умолчанию аккаунт "Действующий"
}
public class Email
{
    public enum emailTypes
    {
        Work,
        Home
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public emailTypes Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [DisplayName("E-mail")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmailTypeSelectListItems
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (emailTypes type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(emailTypes)))
            {
                var selectListItem = new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                             Text = type.ToString(),
                                             Value = type.ToString(),
                                             Selected = this.Type == type
                                         };
                yield return selectListItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Phone
{
    public enum phoneTypes
    {
        Work,
        Mobile
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public phoneTypes Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    [DisplayName("Телефон")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PhoneTypeSelectListItems
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (phoneTypes type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(phoneTypes)))
            {
                var selectListItem = new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                             Text = type.ToString(),
                                             Value = type.ToString(),
                                             Selected = this.Type == type
                                         };
                yield return selectListItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class ProfileUpdate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public enum addressTypes
    {
        Visiting,
        Home
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public addressTypes Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Адрес 1")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Адрес 2")]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Почтовый индекс")]
    public int PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Город")]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AddressTypeSelectListItems
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (addressTypes type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(addressTypes)))
            {
                var selectListItem = new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                             Text = type.ToString(),
                                             Value = type.ToString(),
                                             Selected = this.Type == type
                                         };
                yield return selectListItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Active, true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Телефон", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="phoneList">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Phones.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="phoneRow">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Phones[" + i + "].Type", Model.Phones[i].PhoneTypeSelectListItems, new { @class = "phoneType form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Phones[i].Value, new { placeholder = "Номер телефона", @class = "phoneNumber form-control" })
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowPhone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addRowPhone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Добавить номер</a>
            </p>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phones, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Email", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="emailList">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Emails.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="emailRow">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Emails[" + i + "].Type", Model.Emails[i].EmailTypeSelectListItems, new { @class = "emailType form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Emails[i].Value, new { placeholder = "Электропочта", @class = "emailValue form-control" })
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowEmail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addRowEmail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Добавить Email</a>
            </p>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Emails, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Адрес", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="addressList">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Addresses.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="addressRow">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Adresses[" + i + "].Type", Model.Addresses[i].AddressTypeSelectListItems, new { @class = "addressType form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Addresses[i].PostalCode, new { placeholder = "Почтовый индекс", @class = "addressPostalCode form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Addresses[i].Town, new { placeholder = "Город", @class = "addressTown form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Addresses[i].Street1, new { placeholder = "Улица", @class = "addressStreet1 form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Addresses[i].Street2, new { placeholder = "Номер дома или квартиры", @class = "addressStreet2 form-control" })
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowAddress"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addRowAddress"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Добавить Адрес</a>
            </p>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Addresses, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Контроллер:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Customer customer)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.View(customer);
        }

        var result = await this.db.Customers.Include(a => a.Addresses).Include(a => a.Phones).Include(a => a.Emails).Include(a => a.ProfileUpdates).SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == customer.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result == null)
        {
            return this.HttpNotFound();
        }

        customer.ProfileUpdates = new[] { new ProfileUpdate { UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now } };
        this.db.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(customer);
        await this.db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В одном из вопросов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38527273/5752652) нашёл упоминание (см. [отсылку к MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), что Entity Framework не обновляет навигационные свойства:

> **Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context**
>
> If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but
>   to which changes may have been made then you can tell the context to
>   attach the entity and set its state to Modified. For example:
>
> ```
> var existingBlog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Name = "ADO.NET Blog" }; 
>
> using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
> { 
>     context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified; 
>
>     // Do some more work...  
>
>     context.SaveChanges(); 
> }
> ```
>
> When you change the state to Modified all the properties of the entity
>   will be marked as modified and all the property values will be sent to
>   the database when SaveChanges is called.
>
> Note that if the entity being attached has references to other
>   entities that are not yet tracked, then these new entities will
>   attached to the context in the Unchanged state—they will not
>   automatically be made Modified. If you have multiple entities that
>   need to be marked Modified you should set the state for each of these
>   entities individually.

Так что действительно, пытаясь обновить сущность - у нас обновится только она, без обновления списков телефонов/емейлов/адресов.

Далее. Раскопал вот такие любопытные вопросы:

- [The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5538974/5752652)
- [ASP.NET MVC / EF4 / POCO / Repository - How to Update Relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663727/5752652)
- [Update relationships when saving changes of EF4 POCO objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3635326/5752652)

В общем, я пришёл <s>примерно</s> к тому же виду, что и у Ladislav Mrnka:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        return this.View(contact);

    var entity = db.Contacts.Include(x=>x.Phones).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == contact.Id);
    if (entity == null)
        return this.HttpNotFound();

    this.db.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(contact);

    foreach (var child in contact.Phones)
    {
        var originalChild = entity.Phones.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == child.Id && c.Id != 0);
        if (originalChild == null)
            entity.Phones.Add(child);
        else
            this.db.Entry(originalChild).CurrentValues.SetValues(child);
    }

    //TODO: Удаление удалённых сущностей

    this.db.SaveChanges();
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Другой вариант - использовать [RefactorThis.GraphDiff](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff), описание [тут](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        return this.View(contact);

    var entity = db.Contacts.Include(x=>x.Phones).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == contact.Id);
    if (entity == null)
        return this.HttpNotFound();

    this.db.UpdateGraph(contact, map => map.OwnedCollection(p => p.Phones));

    this.db.SaveChanges();
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Увы, но поддержки EF Core [пруф](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff/issues/164) пока нет :(

Answer (score 0):

После этих изменений все успешно редактируется и сохраняется.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Customer customer)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.View(customer);
        }

        try
        {
            var result = await this.db.Customers.Include(a => a.Addresses).Include(a => a.Phones).Include(a => a.Emails).Include(a => a.ProfileUpdates).SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == customer.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return this.HttpNotFound();
            }

            result.Name = customer.Name;
            result.Notes = customer.Notes;
            result.Active = customer.Active;
            result.Addresses = customer.Addresses;
            result.Emails = customer.Emails;
            result.Phones = customer.Phones;
            result.ProfileUpdates.Add(new ProfileUpdate() { UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now });

            await this.db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                                         "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                                         "see your system administrator.");
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Пробовал воспроизвести проблему и ваш способ решения - не работает. Видимо, чем-то наши примеры различаются... Но сколько всего интересного нашлось по дороге.