# Динамически формы с мультиэлементами в Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

Есть простая база данных клиентов. В ней 2 таблицы, в одной из которых клиент с информацией и 2 таблица с его почтовыми ящиками. Внешний ключ связывает эти таблицы по `id` клиента. Есть такой код добавления на бекенде в базу данных:

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = new Customer
    {
        CompanyName = request.CompanyName,
        Country = request.Country,
        City = request.City,
        Address = request.Address,
        ZipCode = request.ZipCode,
    };
    _context.Customers.Add(entity);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    foreach (var createCustEmail in request.Emails)
    {
        _context.CustomerEmails.Add(new CustomerEmail()
        {
            CustomerId = entity.CustomerId,
            Email = createCustEmail.Email,
        });
    }
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return Unit.Value;
}
```

Вопрос заключается в том,как сделать  добавление емейлов на стороне клиента в Razor Pages?

Comment: зачем, Вам это?

Comment: @Yaroslav все логично же, у одного пользователя может быть несколько емейлов. Пытаюсь это реализовать на простом сайте

Comment: Не совсем понятно, с чем у вас вопрос. Сохранять в БД вы видимо умеете, знаете, пользуетесь MediatR. А для вас вопрос, как упаковать это в работу с Razor Page?

Comment: @retreatretreat, может быть, но зачем в Razor Page не могу понять.

Comment: @AK как сделать это добавление в Razor pages, на стороне клиента. Проблема, что как добавить этот foreach код в cshtml

Comment: ну как то так  @foreach(mail in ViewBag.Emails){   <span>@mail</span>  }  https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/7.3.php

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно сделать, чтобы появлялось новое поле для ввода мейла, когда заполнена предыдущее? И потом отослать их все на сервер?

Comment: Типа такого: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28822953/5045688 ?

Comment: Вы взялись за очень сложную тему - мультиэлементы и они уходят в три очень неочевидных и непростых вопросы. Я мог бы дать ответ но не для razor pages (ну уж для классического asp - точно смогу), у них похоже добавляется ещё один  сложный аспект (не работают EditorTemplates)

Comment: @AK можете,пожалуйста,поделиться ответом для классического asp. Мне уже важнее понять принцип работы глобально.

Comment: Добавил метку asp.net-mvc на вопрос и написал ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У меня есть несколько разных солюшенов, которые отрабатывают разные аспекты мультиформ, вопрос реально достаточно объёмный, поэтому вам рекомендую сделать так же: прежде, чем делать реальное приложение сделать несколько тестовых, чтобы поиграться и посмотреть отдельные аспекты.

Во-первых, вы можете начать с приложения в котором у вас модель емейла будет представлять простую строку:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string[] Phones { get; set; }
}
```

Это иногда очень удобно, в этом случае рекомендую [посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500734/213987) как хранить подобные структуры в базе используя Entity Framework.

Мы же будем начинать с двух полноценных моделей (т.е. телефону нужно хранить не только сам номер, но и допустим тип - рабочий/домашний/факс)

Модель контакта (мысленно можете заменять на Customer):

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        this.Phones = new List<Phone>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

Модель телефона (показаны только ключевые поля):

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Далее тупо создаём CRUD-контроллер, используя scaffolding. Вы наверное многократно видели подобные заготовки, в них нет ничего сложного, но увы, они не умеют в мультиэлементы.

Что нужно сделать. Во-первых, добавить в форму блок для отображения div'а с телефонными номерами:

```
    <div id="phoneList">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Phones)
        <p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addRowPhone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Добавить номер</a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Целиком файл формы Create:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="phoneNumbers">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Phones)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Чтобы эта конструкция заработала - нужно добавить папку Views\Contacts\EditorTemplates и в ней расположить файл Phone.cshtml (который и будет определять как отобразить наш элемент редактирования:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Phone

<div class="phoneRow">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ContactId)
    <p>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Number)
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowPhone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a>
</div>
```

Итого, получается что-то типа:

[image: project structure]

И выглядит как-то так (стилями css не украшал, так как проект учебный, поэтому выглядит страшненько):

[image: Edit form]

Почитайте букварь по этой теме, чтобы понимать, как это работает: [Переопределение шаблонов отображения и редактирования](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.15.php)

В asp.net core принято создавать формы используя тэг-хелперы и аналога для Html.EditorFor я не знаю, но когда я смешал два стиля и прописал Html.EditorFor - оно сработало. Ну это просто некрасиво, слишком разнородный стиль.

Но основная проблема связана с тем, что [шаблоны DisplayTemplates/EditorTemplates для razor pages не работают](https://www.telerik.com/forums/editortemplate-not-working-on-core-2-1-razor-pages), даже в 2.1 - по крайней мере когда я пробовал и в /Pages и в /Views/Shared разные варианты не сработал ни один, увы ;(

Поэтому я и показывать стал на классическом asp'е, тем более что и проекты есть готовые ;)

Какие подводные камни вас ещё ждут. Когда вы получаете данные с формы - всё у вас хорошо, но когда вы начинаете сохранять телефоны при редактировании - вам нужно определять какие из телефонов были удалены, какие добавлены и какие изменились -- и соответственно, удалённые - удалить из базы, новые добавить, а остальные изменить.

Это отдельная большая тема, которая выпивает множество крови. Я вас отправлю к вот [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/788258/213987) и [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455190/213987) вопросу, но будьте готовы потратить несколько дней на эту коварную тему, в этой ветке я просто обозначаю проблему.

При помощи GraphDiff у вас получится сократить код до примерно такого:

```
    // POST: Contacts/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            return this.View(contact);

        var entity = db.Contacts.Include(x=>x.Phones).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == contact.Id);
        if (entity == null)
            return this.HttpNotFound();

        this.db.UpdateGraph(contact, map => map.OwnedCollection(p => p.Phones));

        this.db.SaveChanges();
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

А на ванильном c# код будет раза в четыре больше.

Другой момент будет как смапить ваши классы на MediatR, это смотрите сами по конкретному проекту.

И ещё один момент я упустил - javascript на кнопочках добавления/удаления записей. Я его в тестовом проекте не делал, да и он различается для ванильного js/jQuery/vue/etc - поэтому пишите свой по месту.