# Количество элементов на странице в зависимости от введенного числа

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в ASP.NET CORE MVC сделать так, чтобы по вводу нужного числа в текстовом поле во view, появлялось количество элементов (текстовых полей) на странице равное числу введенному пользователем.

Comment: Вы ждете готовый код для вашей задачи или какой ответ ожидаете увидеть?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918011/184217 - посмотрите это.

Answer (score 1):

Я отвечу именно на заданный вопрос.

Пользователь вводит число в текстовое поле, нажимает кнопку - добавляются новые текстовые поля.

В примере нет отправки данных из этих полей в контроллер. Нет стилизации. Потому что этого нет в вопросе.

View:

```
<input type="number" id="countInput" />

<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addInputs()" />

<div id="inputDiv"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addInputs() {
    var count = document.getElementById("countInput").value;
    var inputDiv = document.getElementById("inputDiv");

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        inputDiv.appendChild(input);
    }
}
```