# Добавить данные в связанные таблицы ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view

Как добавить одновременно данные в связанные таблицы ASP.NET MVC
и в дальнейшем добавлять в коллекцию. Какой должен быть View для передачи в данные модели?

```
public class User
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            Phones = new List<Phone>();
        }
}

public class Phone
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set;}
        public int Number{ get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
         return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(User user)
{
         db.Users.Add(user);
         db.SaveChange();
         return View();
}
```

и Сам View

```
@model test.Models.User
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>User</h4>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>

            /*как мне добавить здесь поле для того что бы телефон сразу добавлялся в коллекцию к определенному 
               пользователю*/

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: да тут вариантов просто туча...один из них: делаете 2 вьюхи. Сначала вьюха, которая добавлет телефон (добавляете несколько). Во вьюхе контрая добавляет пользователя ест ьвываливающийся список, в котором будут все телефоны (id и номера).

Comment: Посмотрите тут, практически полный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918011/213987