# Core MVC: добавление экземпляра вложенного класса через JQuery на View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Модель:**

```
class Parent
{
     public List<InnerClass> Objects= new List<InnerClass>();
}

class InnerClass
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

**Контроллер:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Create new model
/// </summary>
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new Parent());
}
```

**View: (Create.cshtml)**

```
 <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("created", "process"))
        {
<table class="table" border="1" width="60%" align="center">
                     <!-- header-->
                     <tr bgcolor="RGB(171, 222, 184)">
                         <td>

<!- кнопка , которая откроет панель  plannedActions_additem_hidden с текстбоксом для ввода InnerClass.Name->
                             <img src="" alt="Add_New_Item" class="img-add-small" onclick="Show_plannedActions_additem_hidden()" />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td>
                             <table class="table" border="1" width="60%" align="center">
                                 <tr bgcolor="RGB(240, 247, 156)">
                                     <td>
<!-- Здесь вводится добавляемое значение для InnerClass.Name и нажимается кнопка Save()-->
                                         <div class="plannedActions_additem_hidden">
                                             <input id="plannedActions_additem_id" type="text" />
<!-- f(x) Save() должно как-то добавить в Parent.Objects новый элемент-->
                                             <img src="" alt="Save" onclick="Save();" ); />
                                             <img src="" alt="Close panel" onclick="Hide()" ); />
                                         </div>
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
        }
 </div>
```

**Вопрос:**
Я планирую сделать интерактивную работу с указанной моделью в одном Представлении, урезанный код которого приведен выше. Я думаю сделать добавление нового элемента в Parent.Objects с помощью дополнительного text-бокса, скрываемого/открываемого с jQuery. Я не пойму, как дать Представлению понять что я хочу добавить в создаваемую модель значение из текстбокса?
Аналог **Parent.Objects.Add( "Name" );** для бэкенда, но в одном Представление.

Может я вообще не туда копаю, поправьте меня пожалуйста.

Спасибо.

Comment: Когда-то давно описывал как делаются мультиэлементы в asp.net: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/918448/213987 посмотрите, может станет более понятно

Comment: @AK спасибо за ссылку, бегло посмотрел - то что надо